# Using ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to reference current Activity

Tags: android

I would like to be able to receive a reference to the currently running activity from an arbitrary class (Utils, etc) without explicitly passing a reference.

I have considered something like this and would like some feedback about possible issues / alternatives.

```
public class MyApp extends Application implements ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks {
    private Activity currentActivity;

    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity){
        this.currentActivity = activity;
    }

    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity){
        if(this.currentActivity == activity)
            this.currentActivity = null;
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
        return this.currentActivity;
    }
}
```

Theoretically this should only hold a reference to the last resumed activity and allow other activities to be properly collected

Comment: I don't see any problem with this implementation. I actually use `ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks` for tracking activities and app going to background/foreground

Comment: After further consideration the largest issue with this approach is Activity state.  You need to be careful that your activity is not finishing or in another state that might cause crashes or memory leaks.